# Foreign Key Constraint Failure - Django. Manual assignment of Foreign Key to Model via POST Request

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm working on a timesheet based system currently. I am getting a Foreign Key constraint failure when I am trying to assign the foreign key of one model to the other one.

Here are the two models

```
 class Timesheet(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50, blank=True, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    First_Name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    Last_Name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    Date_Created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    Creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    Approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    Company_Relationship = (
        ('Supplier', 'Supplier'),
        ('Contractor', 'Contractor'),
        ('Employee', 'Employee')
    )
    Worker_Type = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=Company_Relationship)
    Total_Days_Worked = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=3)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']
        #unique_together = ['Creator', 'Work_Week']

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('timesheet-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})



class InternalSheet(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50, blank=True, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    Timesheet_id = models.ForeignKey(Timesheet, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    Working_For = (
        ('7', 'Seven'),
        ('i', 'intelligent'),
        ('S', 'Sata'),
    )
    iPSL = (
        ('R16.1', 'Release 16.1'),
        ('R16', 'Release 16')
    )
    Company_name = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=Working_For)
    Company_name_change = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=Working_For)
    Internal_Company_Role = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=iPSL)
    DaysWorked = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=3)
    Managers = (
        ('GW', 'Greg Wood'),
        ('JC', 'Jamie Carson')
    )
    ManagerName = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=Managers)
    Approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('sheet-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

My issue is that I am getting a foreign key failure using this post request.

```
class TimesheetCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
"""
Creates view and send the POST request of the submission to the backend.
"""
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    internal_form_loop = create_internal_form_for_context()
    context = {'form': CreateTimesheetForm(), 'UserGroup': User()}
    context.update(internal_form_loop)
    print("new", context)
    return render(request, 'create.html', context)

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = CreateTimesheetForm(request.POST)
    internal_form_1 = CreateInternalSheetForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        print("forms valid")
        external_timesheet = form.save(commit=False)
        print("self", self.request.user)
        print("id", Timesheet.id)
        external_timesheet.Creator = self.request.user
        external_timesheet.save()
    else:
        print("Error Here")

    if internal_form_1.is_valid():
        print("Internal form valid")
        internal = internal_form_1.save(commit=False)
        internal.Timesheet_id_id = Timesheet.id

        internal.id = uuid.uuid4()
        internal.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('timesheet-detail', args=[Timesheet.id]))
    return render(request, 'create.html', {'form': form, 'UserGroup': User()})
```

It is failing on the line internal.save(). If I print the line internal.Timesheet_id_id I get a value like this, <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x000001580FDB75E0>. I'm guessing this is the issue? I need the actual Foreign key and not the location of that object. How do I do this. Thanks.

Comment: `Timesheet.id` here `Timesheet` is your **model** hence `Timesheet.id` is the id field of the model and **not** an id. I assume you want to write `internal.Timesheet_id_id = external_timesheet.id`...

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue, I had to replace the lines

```
internal.Timesheet_id_id = Timesheet.id
internal.id = uuid.uuid4()
internal.save()
```

with

```
internal.Timesheet_id_id = Timesheet.objects.get(id=external_timesheet.id)
internal.save()
```